# trying to make bat file open diablo2 in windowed mode

Tags: windows, batch-file, windowed

I have `diablo2` and I got a mod for it which opens the game with a `.bat` file.

However it opens it in fullscreen mode which reduces fps and seems to cause mouse lag. I want the functionality of the `bat` file but to open the game in windowed mode.

```
@echo off
Path ..
game
```

So has anyone got anything I can do to that `bat` file to make the game open in windowed mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing:

```
game
```

To:

```
game -w
```

Or:

```
game -w -nofixaspect
```

Comment: that worked instantly aswell. thank you very much :D

Comment: do you also know how i can set a resolution on that?

Comment: @m0nk3n, the resolution is probably fixed at `800x600`, meaning that the only way to have it bigger is to reduce your screen resolution to something you feel comfortable with, _(I don't recommend it as part of a batch file and it is out of the scope of your original question)_.